# How do I select drop down web browser C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I need to know how to select the month. I've tried:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").SetAttribute("value", "Jan");
```

I used something else:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").Children[1].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
```

But it doesn't recognize that it changed.

HTML Code:
Found rest of the HTML code, Don't know if what else I got will help or anything with what I'm trying to do..

```html
<div class="birthday-container">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : isBirthdayInvalid(),
                                                        'has-success' : isBirthdayFormDirty()
                                                                        &amp;&amp; !isBirthdayInvalid() }">
                <label class="birthday-label">Birthday</label>
                <div class="form-control fake-input-lg">
                    <div class="rbx-select-group month">
                        <select class="input-field rbx-select ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-birthday ng-not-empty ng-touched" id="MonthDropdown" tabindex="1" rbx-valid-birthday="" rbx-form-interaction="" rbx-form-validation="" name="birthdayMonth" ng-model="signup.birthdayMonth" ng-change="onChange()">
                            <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Month</option>
                                    <option value="Jan">January</option>
                                    <option value="Feb">February</option>
                                    <option value="Mar">March</option>
                                    <option value="Apr">April</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="Jun">June</option>
                                    <option value="Jul">July</option>
                                    <option value="Aug">August</option>
                                    <option value="Sep">September</option>
                                    <option value="Oct">October</option>
                                    <option value="Nov">November</option>
                                    <option value="Dec">December</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rbx-select-group day">
                        <select class="input-field rbx-select ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-birthday" id="DayDropdown" tabindex="1" rbx-valid-birthday="" rbx-form-interaction="" rbx-form-validation="" name="birthdayDay" ng-model="signup.birthdayDay" ng-change="onChange()">
                            <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Day</option>
                                <option value="1">



                                    01
                                </option>
                                <option value="2">



                                    02
                                </option>
                                <option value="3">



                                    03
                                </option>
                                <option value="4">



                                    04
                                </option>
                                <option value="5">



                                    05
                                </option>
                                <option value="6">



                                    06
                                </option>
                                <option value="7">



                                    07
                                </option>
                                <option value="8">



                                    08
                                </option>
                                <option value="9">



                                    09
                                </option>
                                <option value="10">



                                    10
                                </option>
                                <option value="11">



                                    11
                                </option>
                                <option value="12">



                                    12
                                </option>
                                <option value="13">



                                    13
                                </option>
                                <option value="14">



                                    14
                                </option>
                                <option value="15">



                                    15
                                </option>
                                <option value="16">



                                    16
                                </option>
                                <option value="17">



                                    17
                                </option>
                                <option value="18">



                                    18
                                </option>
                                <option value="19">



                                    19
                                </option>
                                <option value="20">



                                    20
                                </option>
                                <option value="21">



                                    21
                                </option>
                                <option value="22">



                                    22
                                </option>
                                <option value="23">



                                    23
                                </option>
                                <option value="24">



                                    24
                                </option>
                                <option value="25">



                                    25
                                </option>
                                <option value="26">



                                    26
                                </option>
                                <option value="27">



                                    27
                                </option>
                                <option value="28">



                                    28
                                </option>
                                <option value="29">



                                    29
                                </option>
                                <!-- ngIf: isValidBirthday(30,true) --><option value="30" ng-if="isValidBirthday(30,true)" class="ng-scope">



                                    30
                                </option><!-- end ngIf: isValidBirthday(30,true) -->
                                <!-- ngIf: isValidBirthday(31,true) --><option value="31" ng-if="isValidBirthday(31,true)" class="ng-scope">



                                    31
                                </option><!-- end ngIf: isValidBirthday(31,true) -->
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rbx-select-group year">
                        <select class="input-field rbx-select ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-birthday" id="YearDropdown" rbx-valid-birthday="" rbx-form-interaction="" rbx-form-validation="" tabindex="1" name="birthdayYear" ng-model="signup.birthdayYear" ng-change="onChange()">
                            <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Year</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p id="signup-BirthdayInputValidation" class="form-control-label input-validation text-error ng-binding" ng-bind="getBirthdayInvalidMessage()"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

By the way if you want the link for what I'm trying to do it for, https://www.roblox.com/account/signupredir

And also, with the code I have now, it says that the birthday is invalid vs. when you manually put it in, it works.

Comment: you need to set selected attribute

Comment: @Steve I used webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").Children[1].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
Same result.

Comment: have you removed the selected attribute from Month option?

Comment: @Steve I'm new to C# I need to have my hand held..
I'm not sure /=

Comment: try webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").Children[0].SetAttribute("selected", ""); and then webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").Children[1].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");

Comment: @Steve says invalid birthday on the website when I try to use that.

Comment: @Steve is there a way that I can make it click the selection in the drop down? That would work too.

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MonthDropdown").Children[1].RaiseEvent("click")

you can find all available methods in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve Doesn't work .-.

Comment: try that on a regular html page and see if it works .if it does then the page you have might have some javascript event that's doing something funny